# Unable to access the "mmcblk0p6" file, on Samsung S5300 Mini Pocket

Tags: file-system

I have rooted my Samsung S5300 Mini Pocket Galaxy, and I have entrie SDK installed on my Windows 7 laptop.

Now via Command Prompt I am able to:

```
adb shell
$ su
#  <--- and get root access
```

However, if I do something like this:

```
cat /dev/block/mmcblk0p6
```

The output in my CMD prompt is BLANK, and it's like the file is empty.

I've been instaling the **busybox** with all other commands to help me complete this, but I have not accomplished nothing.

Any advices, tips how can I stream into the contents of this particular file?

BTW - I've been trying with Android Commander, but no success either. It says that the file is "empty" => 0 KB.

Thanks all.

Comment: That "particular file" is a block *device*, not an ordinary file. I don't know what you expect in there (I'm not familiar with the device), but it might be some partition. So maybe additionally to what you just tried, you tell us what the problem behind it is? What for do you need/want to "stream into the contents"?

Comment: As I've read elsewhere, supposedly the variable "UN_lock_code" is hidden in that file, which calculated with IMEI can give out the Sim Unlocking Code for these divices. That's why I'm trying to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/block/mmcblk0p6` is not a real file, it is a virtual file representing a block device (that is why it's in `/dev/block`). 'mmcblk0p6' denotes that it's the sixth partition of the first MMC card. I am not really sure why you want to `cat` that file.

Comment: please read my comment on my question, I've explained all there. thanks